# Django detecting changed ImageField with same filename

Tags: django

I'm attempting to detect changes to an ImageField in order to programatically sync the changes with Hg. The model containing the ImageField is being localized using Django-multilingual, so I have to detect changes for each field individually rather than just assume the file changed every time.

I am using pre and post save signals to accomplish this, saving the instance in the pre-save and detecting the changes in the field values in the post-save. This works great for when images are added, removed, or changed with an image of a different filename. However, when I upload an image of the same filename, my code is unable to detect that the image actually changed so no file changes get synced with Hg.

I want to be able to generate a checksum for the old file (easily done as I know where it lives from the presave instance), and compare this to a checksum of the new file (not as easy, as trying to pull it in from the field value takes me to the old file).

If there is a way for me to find the newly uploaded file (presumably in memory as Django doesn't temp save files under 2.5MB), and save it to a temporary directory, it would be easy for me to generate a checksum for it. However, I am not sure where I would get the file from.

Where could I get the file from during a post_save signal? Or is there another method of accomplishing this change detection that I haven't thought of?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this snippet"

```
def has_changed(instance, field):
        if not instance.pk:
            return False
        old_value = instance.__class__._default_manager.\
                 filter(pk=instance.pk).values(field).get()[field]
        return not getattr(instance, field) == old_value
```

then in your save

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if has_changed(self, 'field_here'):

            super(Sneetch, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```